# Months to Pay Off a Credit Card function returns NaN or -0.0

Tags: java

This is from the book *Exercises for Programmers* which asks to:
"Write a program that will help you determine how many months it will take to pay off a credit card balance. The program should ask the user to enter the balance of a credit card and the APR of the card. The program should then return the number of months needed."

And gives this formula to implement.

[image]

Not sure where my problem lies, but I keep getting back NaN or -0.0.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

```
public static double timeToPayOff(double APR, double balance, double payment) {
    double months;
    APR /= 36500;

    months = (-1/30) * (Math.log(1 + (balance/payment)) * ( 1 - (Math.pow((1 + APR), 30)))
            /Math.log(1 + APR));

    return months;
}
```

Comment: What are the values in the formular? What is b what is p what is i? That would be nice to know.

Comment: You should be aware that `APR /= 36500;` and `(-1/30)` are integer divisions. What happens if you use `APR /= 36500.0` and `(-1/30.0)`?;

Comment: Also what IQV says, your programm fails by multiplying with `0` as `(-1/30)` will always be 0.

Comment: 'b' is balance, 'p' is payment, APR, divided by 365, is 'i'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is because you try to calculate different type :

If you want calculate with double, all your variable need to be double so change :

```
months = (-1.0/30.0)
```

With integer this will return 0

---

You also have a problem with the correctness of your formula. You've written the top half of the fraction as

```
Math.log(1 + (balance/payment)) * (1 - (Math.pow((1 + APR), 30)))
```

Whereas it should actually be

```
Math.log(1 + ((balance/payment) * (1 - (Math.pow((1 + APR), 30)))))
```

Comment: All the brackets were confusing, but you have solved my problem.

Now I can die a peaceful death.