# Months to Pay Off a Credit Card in Python 3 wrong expected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing the same problem listed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOklN.png) but in python 3 and not getting the exact expected results so my main formula is off. I tried few things but when I do it creates a ValueError math domain error depending if I use parenthesis are certain parts of the equation.I tried looking at the other thread that had same problem but no luck. Thanks in advance!!!

This one. num_of_months = (-1/30) * (math.log(1 + ((balance/monnthly_payment)) * (1 - ((1 + daily_rate)**30)))
            /math.log(1 + daily_rate));

[Months to Pay Off a Credit Card problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984561/months-to-pay-off-a-credit-card-function-returns-nan-or-0-0)

```
import os
import math

os.system('cls')

def calculateMonthsUntilPaidOff(bal,apr,monthlyPayment):
    balance = bal
    daily_rate = apr / 365
    monnthly_payment = monthlyPayment

    num_of_months = (-1/30) * (math.log(1 + (balance/monnthly_payment)) * (1 - ((1 + daily_rate)**30))
            /math.log(1 + daily_rate))

    return num_of_months

balance = int(input("What is your balance? "))
apr = int(math.ceil(float(input("What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? "))))
monnthly_payment = int(input("What is the monthly payment you can make? "))

months_to_pay_off = calculateMonthsUntilPaidOff(balance,apr,monnthly_payment)

print(f"It will take you {months_to_pay_off} months to pay off this card.")

"""
Test Results:
What is your balance? 5000
What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? 12
What is the monthly payment you can make? 100
It will take you 6.640964973685612 monhts to pay off this card.


Expected Results:
What is your balance? 5000
What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? 12
What is the monthly payment you can make? 100
It will take you 70 months to pay off this card.
"""
```

Comment: i see a semicolon in your code :D thats normaly not a good sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error and wrong calc was caused by your formula

APR should be `float`:

> apr = int(math.ceil(float(input("What is the APR on the card (as a
>   percent)? "))))

So if you input `0.12` and cast `int` and `math.ceil()` it will return `1` [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)

I splitted the calculation for a better overview :)

*Tipp: split your calc for overview and test with a fixed input of numbers before consider a user input.*

```
import os
import math

os.system('cls')

def calculateMonthsUntilPaidOff(bal,apr,monthlyPayment):
    balance = bal
    daily_rate = apr / 100 / 365 # added as percentage
    monnthly_payment = monthlyPayment

    r1 = -1/30
    r2 = math.log(1+ (balance/monnthly_payment) * (1- math.pow((1 + (daily_rate)), 30)))
    r3 = math.log(1+daily_rate)

    return r1 * (r2/r3)

balance = int(input("What is your balance? "))
apr = int(input("What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? "))
monnthly_payment = int(input("What is the monthly payment you can make? "))

months_to_pay_off = months_to_pay_off = math.ceil(calculateMonthsUntilPaidOff(balance,apr,monnthly_payment))

print(f"It will take you {months_to_pay_off} monhts to pay off this card.")

"""
Test Results:
What is your balance? 5000
What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? 12
What is the monthly payment you can make? 100
It will take you 70 monhts to pay off this card.


Expected Results:
What is your balance? 5000
What is the APR on the card (as a percent)? 12
What is the monthly payment you can make? 100
It will take you 70 months to pay off this card.
"""
```

Comment: "daily_rate = apr / 100 / 365 # added as percentage " just realized I didn't do this part right since its a percentage and forgot to divide 100. Thanks